# An Inequality of Conditional Expected Value

Tags: statistics, probability, reinforcement-learning, trading, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to understand the following inequality. Inequality marked with (*), as described in the paper, is because of indecency of some random variables. Considering the information and description they have given in the figure below, how can we say that such an inequality exist?[image]

This is taken from paper: "Bilateral Trade: A Regret Minimization Perspective"